# Excel: How to program to have Excel read a cells contents then switch open a new worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel, basic

I'm very new to programming (1 day experience) and I am trying to build an interactive database but I keep running into issues with having a certain part work.

I want Excel to read the value selected in a certain cell and based on the value in that cell then have it open to a separate sheet, where I can begin another set of data entry.

I have tried a number of different options but as of now, my code looks like this:

```
Dim inputWks As Worksheet
Set inputWks = ("Input")

With inputWks
    If Range("D13").contents = "Yes" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets2").activate
    End If
End With
```

I know this is a simple question but I have not been able to have this work..

Comment: As long as you are just getting started, you may want to review [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: I will definitely look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim inputWks As Worksheet
    Set inputWks = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input")

    With inputWks
        If Range("D13").Cells(1, 1) = "Yes" Then
           ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets2").Activate
        End If 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be missing a `.` in `.Range("D13").Cells(1, 1)`.

Comment: This is still not working for me for some reason. I think that the code is running because there is no error messaging be brought up though.

I cant link the full code but I got it http://www.contextures.com/exceldataentryupdateform.html in case anyone is interested. Credit to www.contextures.com for the model!

Comment: Try it with a period in front of `.Range("D13")`. The period mean that the parent worksheet is the one specified in the With statement (e.g. the worksheet named **Input**).

Comment: By default, VBA is also case-sensitive in text comparisons and a leading or trailing space will invalidate the text comparison.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to be the issue. There is nothing on the sheet, could that be part of the problem?